# How do I get the right output for this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to obtain specific outputs for an array.  The array's been put in a while loop to continue to set up new arrays until it reaches its counter.  The counter and the amount of elements in each array line up, but once I try to get my output, it doesn't work out.  What should I fix to work it out?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;  int j;  int n;  int u;

    int count = 0;

    n = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Times repeated: " + n);


    while(count < n) //counter represents amount of times loop will occur
    {
        i = input.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[i];
        System.out.println("Length of Array: " + i);//represents how many numbers within a line
        count++;

        for(j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) //numbers within line
        {
            numbers[j] = input.nextInt();}
            for(int p = 0; p < numbers.length - 1; p++) //prints specific values in line

            {


            numbers[p] = numbers[numbers.length - 1 ];
            p = numbers[p];
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers)); }

    input.close();}
 }  }
```

First User Input:

3

2

10

1

Expected Output:
10

Instead, I get 1. What I wanted to do was subtract the last element of the array from the rest of the array to get the desired output.  This includes the last element as well.

Comment: Please fix your formatting and count your brackets.

Comment: used input and expected output might help getting an answer..

Comment: @smokedeel have a look , small issue with the code. `close scanner outside while`

Answer (score 0):

code works fine, just need to `close scanner outside while.` Fix the brackets.

`input.close();` outside while loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        int j;
        int n;
        int u;

        int count = 0;

        n = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Times repeated: " + n);

        while (count < n) // counter represents amount of times loop will occur
        {
            i = input.nextInt();
            int[] numbers = new int[i];
            System.out.println("Length of Array: " + i);// represents how many numbers within a line
            count++;

            for (j = 0 ; j < numbers.length ; j++) // numbers within line
            {
                numbers[j] = input.nextInt();
            }
            for (int p = 0 ; p < numbers.length - 1 ; p++) // prints specific values in line

            {

                numbers[p] = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
                p = numbers[p];
                System.out.println(p);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
            }

        }

        input.close();
    }
```

**output**

```
2
Times repeated: 2
2
Length of Array: 2
1
2
2
[2, 2]
2
Length of Array: 2
1
2
2
[2, 2]
```

Comment: I inputted the wrong amount of brackets, my mistake.  The input.close(); was outside of while loop.

Comment: @smokedeel yeah it works fine then, i posted the output also.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem I'm finding is that when I try to get an output of 10 from:
3, 2, 10, 1, it outputs 
Times repeated: 3

2
Length of Array: 2
10
1
1
[1, 1]
[1, 1] 
I want it to output 10.

Comment: @smokedeel it will be better if you accept/upvote answer here, post a fresh question with your inputs and exact issue.